# How should I show default silent notification in status bar?

Tags: android

Sorry if it seems childish but I searched everywhere and I couldn't find any answer to this,

I need to show the crossed-melody ,which is shown when you use silent mode in android phones on status-bar.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: you want the image ? or you want to show a notification with that image on status bar?

Comment: @Metalhead1247 Just the crossed melody that appears beside battery.I want a way to show it to user since my app works with volumes and I want to notify user if it's silent or not and I need a way to show that crossed melody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply show a icon on the status bar!

You have to create a **Notification** in the **Notification bar** 
Which  will show you a Icon of your app or you can set your custom icon which will show up on the **Status Bar**

example 
   http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-notification-with-sound-and-icon-tutorial.html

Comment: would u give me a sample piece of code for this Notification usage? I'll be very grateful.

Comment: @user2541758 here is your code http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-notification-with-sound-and-icon-tutorial.html